# Deleting a resilient, abstruse file in a "Soldat" subfolder

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, rename

I am trying to clear out an old flash drive on my Windows 7 computer.  Everything deleted fine, as usual, except one mysterious file.  The name of the file contains an unusual character, as shown in the image, and has no extension.

Attempting to delete the file throws the error "The file name you specified is not valid or too long."  Attempting to rename the file, including to remove the special character, causes the same error.

How can this file be deleted?  Where could this have come from?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just format the flash drive if you intend to delete everything.

If you do not want to format, try command line:

```
del u:\filename
```

Use tab key to auto complete the name. Or use `*.*` instead of file name to delete all files (`u` being the drive letter).